# Interstitial auto-reloading after error?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

What's the behavior of the admob interstitial after an error occurs? It automatically retries to reload the data or not?
In other words I have to write something like:

```
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

        //ERROR MANAGEMENT
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);//Retry
        }
    });
```

Or admob auto-retry to load ad?

Answer (score -1):

in case of error loading interstitial ad, try this code in your adListener's onAdFailedToLoad method :

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

this will create a new request for ad.